# Is it possible to change Windows IME globally?

Tags: windows, cjk, ime

First of all, I am NOT asking about how to change the IME of my own application.

I would like to create a IME toggle program for my own use, like that of Mac OS. Windows 8 got better but Windows 7 sucks at here. Alt+Shift to cycling through more than 2 IMEs are painful. (I use three.) I can assign a shortcut for each language but the keyboard combination sucks and more importantly, there is a bug that the shortcut keeps disappearing.

To create such a program, I need to
1)know the current IME mode (global)
2)set a specific IME mode (globally)

I looked up Windows' IME API, but I could not find any. Is there any way? If there is none, please tell me so. I will also accept that as an answer. If there is any way, just hint me the names of the API, I will search for the details.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer myself.

"GetKeyboardLayout"
PostMessage WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST

Answer (score 1):

The ImmSimulateHotKey function can toggle  IME on windows 7 ,but I find the ImmIsIME function is invalidation on win 7。